# gtk - SelectObject failed and MaskBlt failed

Tags: c, gtk

I'm relatively new in GTK+-2 programming. I'm following a [tutorial](http://vega.inp.nsk.su/~pshatuno/books/gtk-tut1.pdf) about it. 

When I run this program:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <glib.h>

GtkWidget * window;
GtkWidget * value1;
GtkWidget * value2;
GtkWidget * dec1;
GtkWidget * dec2;
GtkWidget * bin1;
GtkWidget * bin2;
GtkWidget * table;
GtkWidget * result;
GtkWidget * label1;
GtkWidget * label2;
GtkWidget * label3;
GtkWidget * btnAdd;
GtkWidget * btnSub;
GtkWidget * box1;
GtkWidget * box2;
GSList * group;
GSList * group2;
void des (GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
    ;
}
void signalevent (GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{

}
gint delete_event( GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent *event, gpointer data )
{
    g_print ("delete event occurred\n");
    return TRUE;
}
void destroy( GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data )
{
    gtk_main_quit ();
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "DECIMAL-BINARY CALCULATOR");
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(window, 300, 300);
    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK (destroy), NULL);
    gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (window), 10);

    table = gtk_table_new(6, 2, TRUE);

    //ROW 1 COL 1
    label1 = gtk_label_new("Value 1: ");
    gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(table), label1, 0,1,0,1);
    gtk_widget_show(label1);

    //ROW 1 COL 2
    value1 = gtk_entry_new();
    gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(table), value1, 1,2,0,1);
    gtk_widget_show(value1);

    //ROW 2 COL 1 and 2
    box1 = gtk_hbox_new(TRUE, 0);
    dec1 = gtk_radio_button_new_with_label(NULL, "DECIMAL");
    gtk_toggle_button_set_active(GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON(dec1), TRUE );
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box1), dec1, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
    gtk_widget_show(dec1);

    group = gtk_radio_button_get_group(GTK_RADIO_BUTTON(dec1));
    bin1 = gtk_radio_button_new_with_label(group, "BINARY");
    gtk_toggle_button_set_active (GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON (bin1), FALSE);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box1), bin1, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
    gtk_widget_show(bin1);

    gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(table), box1, 0, 2, 1, 2);
    gtk_widget_show(box1);

    //ROW 3 COL 1
    label2 = gtk_label_new("Value 2: ");
    gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(table), label2, 0,1,2,3);
    gtk_widget_show(label2);

    //ROW 3 COL 2
    value2 = gtk_entry_new();
    gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(table), value2, 1,2,2,3);
    gtk_widget_show(value2);

    //ROW 4 COL 1 and 2
    box2 = gtk_hbox_new(TRUE, 0);
    dec2 = gtk_radio_button_new_with_label(NULL, "DECIMAL");
    gtk_toggle_button_set_active( GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON(dec2), TRUE );
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box2), dec2, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
    gtk_widget_show(dec2);

    group2 = gtk_radio_button_get_group(GTK_RADIO_BUTTON(dec2));
    bin2 = gtk_radio_button_new_with_label(group2, "BINARY");
    gtk_toggle_button_set_active( GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON(bin2), FALSE );
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box2), bin2, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
    gtk_widget_show(bin2);

    gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(table), box2, 0, 2, 3, 4);
    gtk_widget_show(box2);

    //ROW 5 COL 1
    btnAdd = gtk_button_new_with_label("Add");
    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (btnAdd), "clicked", G_CALLBACK (signalevent), "button");
    g_signal_connect_swapped (G_OBJECT (btnSub), "clicked", G_CALLBACK (des), G_OBJECT (window));
    gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(table), btnAdd, 0,1,4,5);
    gtk_widget_show(btnAdd);

    //ROW 5 COL 2
    btnSub = gtk_button_new_with_label("Subtract");
    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (btnAdd), "clicked", G_CALLBACK (signalevent), "button");
    g_signal_connect_swapped (G_OBJECT (btnSub), "clicked", G_CALLBACK (des), G_OBJECT (window));
    gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(table), btnSub, 1,2,4,5);
    gtk_widget_show(btnSub);

    //ROW 6 COL 1
    label3 = gtk_label_new("Result: ");
    gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(table), label3, 0,1,5,6);
    gtk_widget_show(label3);

    //ROW 6 COL 2
    result = gtk_entry_new();
    gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(table), result, 1,2,5,6);
    gtk_widget_show(result);

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), table);
    GTK_WIDGET_SET_FLAGS (dec1, GTK_CAN_DEFAULT);
    GTK_WIDGET_SET_FLAGS (dec2, GTK_CAN_DEFAULT);
    gtk_widget_grab_default (dec1);
    gtk_widget_grab_default (dec2);
    gtk_widget_show(table);
    gtk_widget_show(window);
    gtk_main();
}
```

It gives many instances of errors like these:

```
Gdk-WARNING : gdkdrawable-win32.c:711: SelectObject failed: The operation completed successfully

Gdk-WARNING : gdkdrawable-win32.c:711: MaskBlt failed: The operation completed successfully
```

This is the screenshot

[image]

where the Decimal and Binary in the program are radio buttons (supposedly).

P.S. Some functions are still empty because it's ongoing. I'm still testing its GUI.

EDIT: I discovered that the errors (or warnings) spawn when I hover the radio buttons.

Comment: It works fine on my debian: https://postimg.org/image/d7uyvgfaz/ and I can not see any error, but why are you showing each widget one by one? just use `gtk_widget_show_all(window);` at the very end.

Comment: `GTK_WIDGET_SET_FLAGS` is deprecated, try removing this line.

Comment: I did remove the set flags as per @Alter Mann advice, but the warning statements are still there.

Comment: Don't follow a GTK 2 tutorial, especially not that one which is 15 years old and 6 years obsolete! If you're trying to learn GTK, follow a GTK 3 tutorial. [This one](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.20/gtk-getting-started.html) I think is actually a distant descendant of the one you are following...